# Why is running as an 1 dimension array?

Tags: c

So, I am trying to make a function that transpose some matrix and save it in another matrix.

In the main function I create a matrix called AB (is a 3D matrix) that is size AB[100][100][2] (in this test) and the terms of the type AB[i][j][0] represents the matrix A and AB[i][j][1] represents the matrix B.

The error is occurring in the big test (AB[100][100][2]) when I run the first loop in the function, that look like that:

```
void transpose(int size, int matrix[][MAX][2], int index, int index_save){

    int auxiliar_matrix[MAX][MAX];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){

        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++){

            auxiliar_matrix[i][j] = matrix[j][i][index];

    }

    save(matrix, index_save, auxiliar_matrix, size) /*this just save the matrix, isnt wrong*/

}
```

The function just do not work for the big case and the error is in the first 3 lines. Any idea?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works. Then come back and [edit] your question, adding what error you get. Optimally provide a [mre], with emphasis on "complete".

Comment: If you want an array of two matrices, you should instead do: `int AB[2][100][100];`

Comment: What is the logic for the transpose of a 3D array?

Comment: user3121023, how its use the malloc in that case?